# Setting platform specific icons in Ionic

Tags: css, ionic-framework

Okay, so this might be either a really simple question and I'll come away feeling sheepish but I've just gotten started using Ionic and I'm just playing around with detailing the UI with icons.

My question is whether or not you can set the icons in an element and have them render differently depending on which platform you build for?

For example, I had a menu item like so

```
<ion-content scroll="false">
  <ul class="list">
    <li class="item"><a href="#/login"><i class="icon ion-locked">Login</a></li> 
  </ul> 
</ion-content>
```

In Ionicons, there is a `ion-locked` icon for both android (`ion-android-locked`) and ios (`ion-ios-locked`)and I was wondering if there is a way to set icons to match their platform during the build process?

It may just be that I end up having seperate branches in git for this, but I'd rather not if there is a simple way to implement this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since Ionic Framework is built on Apache Cordova you can make use of the Apache Cordova Device plugin which ships standard with new projects:

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-device/blob/master/doc/index.md

You can then do something like this:

```
yourApp.controller("ExampleController", function($scope) {
   $scope.devicePlatform = device.platform;
});
```

Then in your HTML you can reference the controller and show the icon based on the platform:

```
<i ng-if="devicePlatform === 'Android' class="icon ion-android-locked">
<i ng-if="devicePlatform !== 'Android' class="icon ion-ios-locked">
```

Notice the **ng-if**.  Depending on what the $scope.devicePlatform is will decide which of the  tags will show.

Regards,

Comment: Ionic actually provides the platform information without having to include a plugin. http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/utility/ionic.Platform/

`$scope.platform = ionic.Platform;`

`<i ng-class="{'ion-android-locked': platform.isAndroid(), 'ion-ios-locked': !platform.isAndroid()}" class="icon"></i>`

Comment: Both are great suggestions, My concern here is that with every html element that needs to be implemented, there is considerably bloat in the views. I'll implemented and see if something presents itse;f along the way. Thanks Guys!

Answer (score 16):

You could customize you scss file.

Take a look you platform assets, index.html has a class

class="platform-android platform-cordova   platform-webview"

```
//default
.your-search{
  @extend .ion-android-search;
}
.platform-android {
  .your-search{
    @extend .ion-android-search;
  }
}

.platform-ios {
  .your-search {
    @extend .ion-ios7-search;
  }
}
```

Comment: I think this is a much more elegant solution than conditionals junking up the html and needing to be repeated whenever reused.  Another option would be to use a directive but still I think that's more code necessary to do something that's this simple.

Comment: this is my preferred solution - this really belongs into the scss/css area and should not clutter the html.

Comment: This approach seems to be the ideal though it's hard to replace icon with text for iOS as they tend to use text instead of icons.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively to [Nic Robody](https://stackoverflow.com/users/498479/nic-raboy)'s approch you can use [`ng-class`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass):

```
app.controller("appCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.devicePlatform = device.platform;
});
```

HTML (using **ng-class**):

```
<i class="icon" ng-class="{
    'ion-android-locked': devicePlatform === 'Android',
    'ion-ios-locked': devicePlatform !== 'Android'
}">
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a cordova CLI hook that replaces certain placeholders with the actual platform or a platform specific value. A prepare hook for example would be called every time you build. Like the "platform add to body" hook that is generated by yeoman for a cordova project. The hook is part of the project, so it's under your control.

Here is a nice overview concerning cordova build hooks: http://devgirl.org/2013/11/12/three-hooks-your-cordovaphonegap-project-needs/

Comment: I'll check it out and report back. Do you have an example specific to the question? Thx

Answer (score 0):

A better solution is to use the ionic.Platform.platform() method to get device platform below:

In your controller:

```
angular.module('App', ['ionic'])
.app.controller("appCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.devicePlatform = ionic.Platform.platform();
});
```

In your html:

```
<i class="icon" ng-class="{
          'ion-arrow-left-c': devicePlatform === 'android',
          'ion-ios-arrow-back': devicePlatform !== 'android'}"> Back</i>
```

Answer (score 0):

Note to future Ionic 2 users who run across this question: As of Ionic 2 RC2, the simplest way to accomplish this is with the "ios" and "md" attributes for the `ion-icon` tag. Here's an example with different icons for iOS and Android ("md" AKA Material Design):

```
<ion-icon ios="ios-outline-lock" md="md-lock"></ios-icon>
```

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth almost 3 years later. Just make your own version of the v2 directive.

```js
function icon() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {},
    compile: function(element, attrs) {
      //change here for specific device default
      var platform = ionic.Platform.platform() || 'ios';
      var iconClass = (platform === 'ios') ? attrs.ios : attrs.droid;
      element[0].classList.add(iconClass);
    }
  };
}

angular
  .module('common.directives')
  .directive('icon', icon);
```

```html
<i class="icon ion-iphone placeholder-icon" icon ios="ion-test" droid="droid-test"></i>
```